# diferencia entre 2 horas tipo TIME, moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Hola a todos buenas tardes, tengo 2 input (hora_inicio_cx y hora_termino_cx) ambos de tipo TIME y estoy tratando de calcular el tiempo transcurrido entre las 2 horas seleccionadas en los input, el tema es que cuando las horas son enteras (por ejemplo 14:00 y 15:00) me calcula 1 (estaria bien ya que hay una diferencia de una hora) pero cuando hago el ejercicio con horas impares (por ejemplo: 13:47 y 15:49 me debiera resultar 2:02 pero me da como resultado: 2.033333333333333)

Tengo este script en JS/JQUERY:

```
$( "#tiempo_total_procedimiento" ).click(function() {
            response = {
           /*  startTime: '08:45',
            endTime: '09:50' */

            startTime: $('#hora_inicio_cx').val(),
            endTime: $('#hora_termino_cx').val()
            };

            var momentStartTime = moment(response.startTime, 'hh:mm');
            var momentEndTime = moment(response.endTime, 'hh:mm');

            var valor = momentEndTime.diff(momentStartTime, 'minutes') / 60 ;

            $('#tiempo_total_procedimiento').val(valor);

            console.log(valor);
```

Lo otro es que no entiendo bien como formatear la salida y que sea asi: 02:00 en lugar de por ejemplo 2

Saludos a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar los getters de moment y luego darle formato tu mismo. Yo haría algo así (asumiendo que `startTime` y `endTime` son objetos `moment`):

```js
const difference = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime)); 
const hours = difference.get('hours');
const minutes = difference.get('minutes');
const valor = `${hours}:${minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}`
```